# An inequality with definite integrals

Tags: real-analysis

I need to prove that the following inequality holds:

$$\int_{0}^{e} \sqrt{e^x-1}  + \int_{0}^{e} \log{(x^2+1)} \geq e^2$$

Any support is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Hint: Use Young's Inequality.

Comment: @David Mitra: OK. Good idea! Thanks.

Comment: @DavidMitra Thats a really good hint hitting the nail on the head. Nice! I think you should add that as answer so that the question gets an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the inverse function of $f(x)=\sqrt{e^x-1}$, $0\le  x\le e$,  is $f^{-1}(x)=\log(x^2+1)$.  So, you may apply the appropriate version of [Young's Inequality.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_inequality)